# How to remove white space around edges of object in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js and have a canvas where I can add shapes to.
But when you resize the objects, there is a white space around the edges that keeps growing as you make the shape bigger. Because of this, you cant place the shape perfectly in the corners.
I already tried setting the padding to 0, but this does nothing.

Does someone know how to remove these white spaces?

EDIT: it has something to do with the background, because if i set the background color of the object to the same color they go away. But if I do this the sizes are not accurate.

But I cant figure out how to remove the background

[image: Here you can see the white space around the edges]

[image: Not in the corner pefectly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, FabricJS objects have a transparent stroke of 1. You can set a strokeWidth of 0 on your objects to avoid this issue.

```
rect.set('strokeWidth', 0);
```

See http://fabricjs.com/fabric-gotchas

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I tried every possibly related attribute. I guess not. This solved it!